# Adding a button onto each row of a table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently looking for a way to insert a button on each row of a table (please note this is a dynamic table that will change on a regular basis), this button would be used for deleting the row from the table - I have already tried adding a button on each row using this method:

```
            foreach (string instrument in splitInstrumentList)
            {
                TableRow r = new TableRow();
                r.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                Button deleteButton = new Button();

                string instrumentString = instrument.ToString();

                if (instrumentString.Contains(","))
                {
                    instrumentString.Replace(",", string.Empty);
                }

                if (instrumentString.Length > 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentString))
                {
                    r.Cells[0].Text = instrumentString;

                    this.instrumentTable.Rows.Add(r);
                    deleteButton.ID = "deleteButton";
                    deleteButton.Text = "Delete";
                    instrumentTable.Controls.Add(deleteButton);

                }
            }
```

However I can not do this due to the fact Table can't use the child type Button which I should of realised anyway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the button in a Row's cell, currently you are adding the button to the table itself. You should create a new Cell and then add the Button to the cell , later add the cell to the row like.

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.Controls.Add(deleteButton);
r.Cells.Add(cell);
```

You should also register an event against the Button Click event before adding it to the cell, where you would perform the delete operation.

Comment: I was planning on doing that after! Thank you though :)

Comment: @HelloWorld, planning to do what ? You should create and add the button to the cell in your loop.

Comment: Register an event for the buttons click, I just missed that out from this part of the code. Thank you very much though.